# printer settings changes when RDP to the terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, terminal-server, printing

Let me explain the problem.

I have network printer mapped on the workstation. Printer on this workstation is set to print as black&white only. I RDP to the Terminal Server and printer is getting populated there as well automatically. Unfortunately after login to terminal server color preferences are changed back to color for this particular printer.

What should I do to get same preferences as on the fat client?

I have heard that it has something to to with initial printer settings on the PC where printer is installed and the advice I got was to uninstall printer from the server, then from all workstations, install it on the server again, set all settings and map it on all workstations.

I was wondering if there is easier way to do it. I will be great for any help. I will provide more information if needed of course.

Regards Mariusz

Comment: Server 2003 or 2008 Terminal Server?

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for editing my post. I am honored :-)

Comment: What is the printer model?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with replacing the driver on the terminal server, with one that is perhaps newer or better matched to the client's driver.

We've made major changes to settings within a few different printer drivers on Server 2008 RDP, and didn't have any issues with the clients logging of and back on. But the drivers we used on the server and PC matched exactly.